# Sonata Admin Custom Controller in Menu Override existing ones

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, knpmenubundle

I try to add a custom Controller/Page to the Knp Menu in Sonata Admin. 
I have bring it allready to work that the menu shows me the link in the navigation. 
I do it like this in the config:

```
    groups:
             User:
                  label:            User
                  items:
                      - route:        user_index
                        label:        User Profile
                      - route:        user_edit
                        label:        User Edit
                      - route:        user_password
                        label:        User Password
                  roles: [ ROLE_USER]
```

My Problem is my existing Sonata Admin Controllers are not shown in the menu when i activate this setting. 
What can i do to add and not override?
What i found is to maybe register a listener and extend there the menu. But i found it must be easier than that.

What is the best way to do this? 
THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding an empty menu item with the same label as the default Sonata items (in my situation that group was called **admin**):

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        # default global templates
        layout: SonataAdminBundle::layout.html.twig
    dashboard:
        groups:
            admin: ~
            User:
                label:            User
                items:
                    - route:        user_index
                      label:        User Profile
                    - route:        user_edit
                      label:        User Edit
                    - route:        user_password
                      label:        User Password
                roles: [ ROLE_USER]
```